# How to use C1InputPanel's InputCombox?

Tags: winforms, controls, componentone

there is little help material on how to use the InputComboBox within the C1InputPanel control. Say i like to have a simple list of strings in the dropdownlist ("item1", "item2", "item3"), default is Item2. By using the generic ComboBox control from WinForm, i can simply use:

```
combobox1.items.clear
combobox1.items.add("items1")
combobox1.items.add("items2")
combobox1.items.add("items3")
combobox1.selectedindex=1
```

but using InputCombobox, how to achieve this?
I use the following to insert each item:

```
dim lb as new InputLabel
lb.text="items1"
combobox1.items.add(lb)
```

is this correct? after that, i see the list gets populated, but the .selectedindex doesn't seem to work, and item can not be selected...

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by reading the sample file from ComponentOne. under the 'DataBinding’ project for C1InputPanel.
The correct way is to use:

```
combobox1.items.add(new c1.win.inputpanel.inputoption("items1″)
….
```

Answer (score 0):

The Items collections of InputComboBox for C1InputPanel supports only InputOption and InputGroupHeader objects. Hence, the correct code would be :

```
dim lb as new InputOption
lb.text="items1"
combobox1.items.add(lb)
```

Thanks,

Richa